# Pandas assign to chained .loc views (not copies) and SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

There seems to be a lot of confusion around the .loc and SettingWithCopyWarning. In my case I could not find a solution to this situation from existing questions.

Currently I have a DF which I would like to filter with slices and then set values to these slices which propagate to the original. So I do not want a copy, I want the view which I modify.

Currently it works with this:

```
A0.loc[(A0['Pääkategoria'].isnull()) & (A0.Määrä < 0) & (A0.SaajaMaksaja.str.contains('|'.join(catfilter))), 'Pääkategoria'] = cat1
```

This will get quite complicated when there are lot of filters to be fullfilled. Is it possible to get views "incrementally" which I work on and then the set values to the view are propagated to the original DF `A0`?

---

Now I have the following which causes: `SettingWithCopyWarning`

```
A1 = A0.loc[(A0['Pääkategoria'].isnull() & (A0.Määrä < 0))]
A1.loc[A1.SaajaMaksaja.str.contains('|'.join(catfilter)), 'Pääkategoria'] = cat1
```

So it seems that the `A1` is only a copy, not a slice. Slicing multiple times would allow me to do slices for different situations (> 0 for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, a much more readable solution which should not cause `SettingWithCopyWarning` is to calculate your partial mask as a separate step.

Then use the `&` operator once within `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
mask = A0['Pääkategoria'].isnull() & (A0.Määrä < 0)

A0.loc[mask & A1.SaajaMaksaja.str.contains('|'.join(catfilter)), 'Pääkategoria'] = cat1
```

Chaining `loc` indexers, as you noticed, is liable to raise `SettingWithCopyWarning`. But this chaining is not necessary to calculate the intersection of Boolean series.

Comment: I would also add that you can put each step in its own function with a name that helps explain what you are doing. Imagine coming back to this in a month or a year and trying to figure out what you are doing. It wouldn’t be fun. By naming the functions and giving them a single responsibility it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks @jpp, didn't think of it this way for some reason. I can chain the masks for clarity if needed and then just use the original DF as the target.

Answer (score 0):

try this one after importing pandas (as pd)

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

just try

Comment: I'm not sure this will work,but it worked for a similar case to me :)

Comment: Chained assignment warnings exists for a reason. Sometimes they indicate a problem, but often they give false positives. I wouldn't recommend this as a general fix.

Comment: yeah i agree ..it is not a general fix.but temporarily it's worth a try.